# I am getting an error called Either Value or Key vault must be provided and Secret Identifier is not in the correct format

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have azure key vault service in which we are maintaining secrets.
I have to deploy APIM service using ARM JOB in Azure devops release pipeline so I have added this job and added configured template.json and parameter.json and how to pass key vault as over ride parameter to ARM job in over ride parameters?. I tried with below option
I have added keyvault job/varaible group in azure pipelines then in over ride params i called $(keyvaultname/secretname) then saved it and ran the pipeline but i am geeting below issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq7yn.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Please go to Pipelines -> Library -> create a variable group which contain the keyvalut.
2. Link the Variable group in your pipeline, make sure the variable of secret is listed.
   [image]
3. In the ARM task, overwrite the parameters with `"$(var)"` name.
   [image]

Comment: I followed same process even though I got same error.

Comment: Please share your a screenshot of your task so we can check the details.

Comment: sure, PFA my variable group screen shot

Comment: Dear Wade Zhou ,while giving comment to you i could not able copy paste or browse images so i clicked on answer to my question and given the screen shots there please check it once .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72611716/16525893

Answer (score 0):

PFA .
I have created Variable group and then came back to release pipeline arm job then in the override parameter .

[Arm job over ride parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh6Dw.png)

[Variable group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVPFX.png)

Comment: Thanks for your sharing! What's the variable format used for parameter overwriting? Please only use `"$(var)"` not contain the keyvault name. To narrow down the issue, please also give a try to add a secret variable directly, use the variable for the task, will it work?
Please also provide a screenshot of the parameter definiton in template and parameter json.